# unit testing functions with Apache Camel Exchange as parameter

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel, junit4, easymock

I am doing java camel development and I want to unit test(junit4) a bunch of functions with Exchange being passed in as parameter.

For example :

```
public finalObject getProperty(final Exchange exchange, final String property) throws Exception {
   //all about getting property from xml message in exchange via xpath
}
```

Question:
1>Can I use EasyMock to mock Exchange ? And how to set a predefined xml as incoming message inside the exchange ?

2>If not do I need to setup camel test ? How to set a predefined xml as incoming message inside the exchange with camel test.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do not you mock endpoints and mock their returned body. See http://camel.apache.org/mock.html http://camel.apache.org/testing.html  You should ideally be focussing on mocking endpoints I guess.

Comment: @Saury: I am not that interested in endponts, all I want to test is the getting the xml message from Exchange. But let's say I have to lock endpoints to get a mock exchange, how do I set the content xml message inside the exchange ?

Answer (score 46):

You can also create a new default exchange like this:

```
    CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
    Exchange ex = new DefaultExchange(ctx);
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice and simple way to mock and unit test Camel processors

Comment: where did this DefaultExchange() method come from?

Comment: @Gerry it is not a method, it is a constructor.